# ghostscript executable search path (with graphicsmagick)

Tags: nginx, debian, ghostscript, graphicsmagick

Ealier I had both `ghostscript` and `graphicsmagick` installed via `apt install ...`, but to support the latest versions I decided to uninstall and instead build and install from source

Before everything worked, but after installing from source `graphicsmagick` commands that require `ghostscript` fails (when running from `nginx`)

Command

```
gm convert -density 50 input.pdf[0] -background white -resize 140x140 -strip -quality 40 thumb.jpg
```

The above command works fine when running it as `root`, but when running it from the webserver `nginx` an error is returned

> execvp failed, errno = 2 (No such file or directory) gm convert: "gs"
> "-q" "-dBATCH" "-dSAFER" "-dMaxBitmap=50000000" "-dNOPAUSE"
> "-sDEVICE=pnmraw" "-dTextAlphaBits=4" "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4"
> "-r50x50" "-dFirstPage=1" "-dLastPage=1" "-sOutputFile=/tmp/gmhjqkzP"
> "--" "/tmp/gmZaShhP" "-c" "quit". gm convert: Request did not return
> an image.

What is the reason for this and how to fix it?

Build and install (from source)

```
# cd /var/bin && wget https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs10021/ghostscript-10.02.1.tar.gz && tar -xvf ghostscript-10.02.1.tar.gz
# cd ghostscript-10.02.1 && ./configure && make -j $(nproc) && make install
```

## update

```
# type gs
gs is hashed (/usr/local/bin/gs)
```

The path `/usr/local/bin` is already included in `/etc/profile`

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

When printing the PATH from nginx (HTTP request)

```
echo shell_exec('echo $PATH');

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

gs permission

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```bash
+-----------------+     calls    +------------------+
|                 |  ----------> |                  |
|  nginx (web)    |              |  graphicsmagick  |
|                 | <----------  |                  |
+-----------------+   requires   +------------------+
                            |
                            |
                            V
                    +-----------------+
                    |                 |
                    |  ghostscript    |
                    |   (from source) |
                    +-----------------+
```

But [`graphicsmagick`](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) does not find [`ghostscript`](https://ghostscript.com/releases/index.html) (mentioned in "[Installing GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/README.html)") when run by the `nginx` user, even though the `gs` path is included in PATH in `/etc/profile`.

Since nginx runs as a specific user (usually `nginx` or `www-data`), this user might not have the same PATH as the root user.
To check the PATH available to the nginx user, you can modify a script run by nginx to include `echo $PATH > /tmp/nginx_path.txt`. That will print the PATH seen by nginx to a file.

If the path to `gs` is `/usr/local/bin/gs`, you can modify the startup script of nginx to include this path. For instance:

```bash
# Edit nginx startup script
sudo nano /etc/init.d/nginx

# Find the section where PATH is set and modify it
# For example:
# PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Or, update the script that calls `graphicsmagick`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Set the PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

# Then call your graphicsmagick command
gm convert -density 50 input.pdf[0] -background white -resize 140x140 -strip -quality 40 thumb.jpg
```

As a workaround, specify the full path to the `ghostscript` executable in your `graphicsmagick` command.

```bash
gm convert -density 50 input.pdf[0] -background white -resize 140x140 -strip -quality 40 \
   -command "/usr/local/bin/gs" thumb.jpg
```

Make sure the nginx user has execute permissions on the `ghostscript` binary.
And check that any security policies or [apparmor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor) profiles are not restricting access to the necessary paths for the nginx user.

---

The [OP clarkk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555222/clarkk) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77812139/ghostscript-executable-search-path-with-graphicsmagick/77823945?noredirect=1#comment137201837_77823945):

> you can configure/build `graphicsmagick` with frozen paths and then you neither need the `PATH` nor to manually pass the full path to gs... `./configure --with-frozenpaths`.

That option makes sure GraphicsMagick remembers the locations of external utilities like `ghostscript` (`gs`) during its build process, eliminating the need to set the PATH environment variable or manually pass the full path to `gs` in your commands.

That method is particularly useful when dealing with environments like that of `nginx`, where setting environment variables can be challenging.

```bash
./configure --with-frozenpaths
make
sudo make install
```

This is similar to [this option](https://imagemagick.org/script/advanced-linux-installation.php):

> ### `--with-frozenpaths`

> Enable frozen delegate paths.
>
> Normally, external program names are substituted into the `delegates.xml` configuration file without full paths.
>
> Specify this option to enable saving full paths to programs using locations determined by configure.
>
> This useful for environments where programs are stored under multiple paths, and users may use different PATH settings than the person who builds ImageMagick.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer, but I already check `PATH`. Look in the updated section in the bottom of the question. `echo shell_exec('echo $PATH');` outputs `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Comment: @clarkk Yes, that is why I mentioned a workaround in the answer: to specify the full path to the `ghostscript` executable in your `graphicsmagick` command.

Comment: I found out you can configure/build graphicsmagick with frozen paths and then you neither need the PATH nor to manually pass the full path to gs... `./configure --with-frozenpaths` you can add it in your answer if you want. I did that and everything works!! :)

Comment: @clarkk Good catch, well done. I have edited the answer accordingly, to document the `--with-frozenpaths` option.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `nginx` user does not have **Ghostscript** (i.e. the `gs` binary) in their PATH, whereas you and the root user do. So the `nginx` user cannot find `gs`, and fails to `exec` it.

The first thing to do is `su` to, or login as, `root` (or any user who can run `ghostscript`), then run:

```
type gs
```

and it will tell you the full path to **Ghostscript**. Then you need to ensure that the `nginx` user has the directory containing `gs` on their PATH.

Another way to find the full path to **Ghostscript** is with:

```
sudo find / -type f -name "gs" 2> /dev/null
```

---

Alternatively, you can alter the **ImageMagick** *"delegates"* file to include the full path to the **Ghostscript** executable. So, you need to find the `delegates.xml` that **ImageMagick** is using like this:

```
identify -list configure | grep CONFIGURE_PATH
```

and that will tell you something like this, though it will be different on **debian** since I am using **homebrew** on a Mac:

```
CONFIGURE_PATH /opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.1-21/etc/ImageMagick-7/
```

Then you need to add `delegates.xml` onto that PATH, to give something akin to:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.1-21/etc/ImageMagick-7/delegates.xml
```

Then, after backing up that file, edit it and change where it says `delegate decode=pdf` so that it has the full path to `ghostscript` there for all users. It looks like this:

```
<delegate decode="pdf" encode="ps" mode="bi" command="&quot;gs&quot; -sstdout=%%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 &quot;-sDEVICE=ps2write&quot; &quot;-sPDFPassword=%a&quot; &quot;-sOutputFile=%o&quot; &quot;-f%i&quot;"/>
```

So, you would need to change it to something more like this with the full path to `gs`:

```
<delegate decode="pdf" encode="ps" mode="bi" command="&quot;/FULL/PATH/TO/gs&quot; -sstdout=%%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 &quot;-sDEVICE=ps2write&quot; &quot;-sPDFPassword=%a&quot; &quot;-sOutputFile=%o&quot; &quot;-f%i&quot;"/>
```

Comment: Thanks mark, but the question is about graphicsmagic. But I'm actually also using imagemagick in a few situiations, but primarily I use graphicsmagick (it has better performance). Can you add some information about how to make it work with graphicsmagick?

Comment: But how to add gs path to PATH in nginx user?

Comment: Did you find the full path to `gs` yet?

Comment: yes found it. But how is `apt install ..` setting the PATH when installing ghostscript? When installing gs from apt install everything works fine also with nginx

Comment: `apt install` never sets your PATH - that's your job.

Comment: but everything works when installing via `apt install ...` Both imagemagick and graphicsmagick works 100% from all users when ghostscript is required. I only have these issues when building from source and installing

Comment: Mmm... if your question is about building from source, you need to [edit] it and show exactly how you built from source.

Comment: So you only installed **Ghostscript** from source, not **GraphicsMagick** from source. So you need to see where **Ghostscript** is installed when you install from source and work out how that is different from when you install via `apt`. Try running `./configure -h` or `./configure --help` in the **Ghostscript** installation directory to see where it installs to... it will be something like `INSTALL_DIR` or `INSTALL_PATH`. Then make it install to the same place that `apt install` puts it, which is where every user can find it.

Comment: Either way, you need to 1) find where `gs`binary is in your filesystem, then 2) either add the containing directory to `nginx` user's PATH, or edit full path into the relevant `delegates.xml`.

Comment: I think you also need `sudo ldconfig` as the final step in your build process.

Comment: Have updated my question where I show that the gs path is included in PATH in `/etc/profile`

Comment: When running `ldconfig` do I have to add any path or is it enough just to run `ldconfig` without any arguments?

Comment: I have never needed a directory - give it a try.

Comment: Have tried `ldconfig` but still same error

Comment: I have updated my question. I have added (exporting) the PATH in `/etc/profile` to add it in nginx user. But it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Okay. Presumably you are *"shelling out"* from an NGINX server to run **ImageMagick** via a `subprocess.run()`? If so, try changing the `subprocess.run()` so that it echoes its PATH and environment (maybe to a file in /tmp)  instead of running **ImageMagick** You can also run `type magick` to see which **ImageMagick** it is actually running. Then diff the environment with one from a shell that works properly. `env` will print your complete environment.

Comment: I am not using imagemagick

Comment: I only use command line not the C++ API